Infer separate types within a multidimensional array based on the first index of the nested tuples
I have a function that accepts a batch of updates which get pushed into a queue to be written to a client-side DB.
The function has 2 overloads to support the main use cases, one of these overloads is an array of updates.
The updates are a tuple of [object name, object data], and I need the type of data to be mapped based upon the given name.
This is easy enough with generics and a mapped type, but issues arise when I try to get the same support in the list of updates.
interface Map {
  Foo: { A: number };
  Bar: { B: string };
}

type Name = Extract<keyof Map, string>;
type Data = Record<string, unknown>;

type Update<N extends Name = Name, D extends Data = PartialDeep<Map[N]>> = [
  name: N,
  data: D,
];
type AgnosticUpdate = Update<Name, Data>;
// overload with list MUST go first for the list usage to get the correct typing and intellisense
// this is likely because the second overload uses a rest parameter, and overloads match first available in the order
// https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1860#issuecomment-72154737
function update<N extends Name>(updates: Update<N>[]): void;
function update<N extends Name>(...[name, data]: Update<N>): void;
function update(nameOrList: Name | AgnosticUpdate[], data?: Data) {
  // ...
}

// single test
update('Foo', { A: 0 }); // pass
update('Foo', { A: '' }); // pass, not assignable
update('Foo', { B: '' }); // pass, not assignable
update('Bar', { B: '' }); // pass
update('Bar', { B: 0 }); // pass, not assignable
// list test
update([
  ['Foo', { A: 0 }], // pass
  ['Foo', { A: '' }], // pass
  ['Foo', { B: '' }], // ISSUE 1
  ['Bar', { B: '' }], // pass
  ['Bar', { A: 0 }], // ISSUE 2
]);
update([
  ['Foo', { A: 0 }],
  ['Foo', { B: '' }], // ISSUE 3
]);
// variable test
const test1: Update = ['Foo', { A: 0 }]; // ISSUE 4
const test2: Update<'Foo'> = ['Foo', { A: 0 }]; // pass

ISSUE 1 & 2:
These are passing because update() is typing as update<'Foo' | 'Bar', { A: number } | { B: string }>, so any data is valid as long as it's present in the Map, no matter what Name it's under.
ISSUE 3:
This correctly fails, but only because Bar is not present in the list so the function is typing as update<('Foo', { A: number })[]>
ISSUE 4:
This passes and it's not really an issue, but test1 is not narrowed to Update<'Foo'> based on the right hand assignment, just wondering if there's a way to get this inference to avoid writing test2.

The problem is that when you're passing an array of different names, the N generic type will be the union of these names, thus D also resolves to a union of their corresponding Mapp[N], you end up with four possible formations (in case there's only Foo and Bar), to avoid that, you need to pass the type check for each name, here's a solution for the problem: Playground. This solution also includes type checking for the fourth issue, but when you hover over test1, the type is a bit unclear.
